# SQL query error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this query:

```
SELECT 
   t1.password 
FROM Session AS t1 
INNER JOIN Locations AS t2 ON 
    t2.id = t1.location_id AND 
    SQRT( POWER( CONVERT(t2.longitude,float(10)) - 132.456, 2) + 
        POWER( CONVERT(t2.latitude,float(10)) - 132.456, 2) ) < 100 
WHERE t1.end_distribution = 0 AND t1.end_session = 0
```

and I get this:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'float(10)) - 132.456, 2) + POWER( CONVERT(t2.latitude,float(10)) - 132.456, 2) )' at line 13

Comment: In MySQL, the syntax for CONVERT is: `CONVERT(expression, type)`; you've got the parameters flip-flopped ([reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert)).

Comment: still have the same problem(see edit)

Comment: I would try wrapping the "Convert(exp, type) - #" in parentheses. I don't know enough about mySQL, but based upon the Near it looks like it is expecting a "," after your float and it's finding a "-". Wrapping it in parentheses might appease the order of operation gods.

Comment: @Love2Learn: The parentheses shouldn't matter. Perhaps `float(10)` isn't a valid conversion type?

Comment: i've tried changing it with int.... nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
CONVERT(t2.longitude, float(10))
```

[MySQL CONVERT SYNTAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert)

**UPDATE**

Depending on documentation above you can't convert expression to type float, use decimal instead.

```
CONVERT(t2.longitude, decimal(10))
```

Comment: @user783476 Are you flipped in both places?

Comment: thank you very much for the update.. i will test this and get right back at you

Answer (score 0):

You've got an invalid specification for the type on the CONVERT function.  `FLOAT(10)` is not valid.  It looks like your best alternative will be to use `DECIMAL`.

From the MySQL Reference Manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html

<snip>

The type for the result can be one of the following values:

```
BINARY[(N)]
CHAR[(N)]
DATE
DATETIME
DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
SIGNED [INTEGER]
TIME
UNSIGNED [INTEGER]
```

</snip>